# Connect SQL Server in Django Docker

Tags: sql-server, django, docker

Outside of Docker, my app works well, and I can connect to two SQL Server databases, on two diferent servers.
Inside Docker, I can't connect to the second DB. I get a timeout error.

Can someone help me?

settings.py

```
DATABASES = { 
    'default': {
        'ENGINE'  : config('DB_ENGINE'), 
        'NAME'    : config('DB_DEFAULT_NAME'),
        'USER'    : config('DB_DEFAULT_USERNAME'),
        'PASSWORD': config('DB_DEFAULT_PASS'),
        'HOST'    : config('DB_HOST_DEFAULT'),
        'PORT'    : '',
        'OPTIONS': {
                    'driver': config('DATABASE_DRIVER'),
                },
        },
    'otherbd': {
        'ENGINE'  : 'mssql', 
        'NAME'    : 'serverbd',
        'USER'    : 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pw',
        'HOST'    : '192.168.1.165',
        'PORT'    : '63649',
        'OPTIONS': {
                    'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
                },
        },  
}
```

views.py

```
def ordens_e_ensaques(request):
    try:
        second_db = connections['otherbd']
        cursor = second_db.cursor()

        # Consulta para obter as ordens
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Ordens WHERE ORD_Estado = '1'")
        print('Consulta SQL de Ordens executada com sucesso!')
        resultados_ordens = cursor.fetchall()

        # Consulta para obter os ensaques
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM OrdensEnsaqueActivas")
        print('Consulta SQL de Ensaques executada com sucesso!')
        resultados_ensaques = cursor.fetchall()

        context = {
            'resultados_ordens': resultados_ordens,
            'resultados_ensaques': resultados_ensaques
        }
        return render(request, 'pages/producoes.html', context)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados: ", e)
        return HttpResponse("Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados: " + str(e))
```

Comment: 63649 are you sure that's the correct port?  I would have expected maybe the default port for mssql which is apparently 1433.  Not some very high # port which are typically used for client side connections.  Generally connecting to an invalid port could cause timeout, if the server was running a firewall that dropped disallowed packets.

Comment: Yes, the port 63649 is correct. In the TCP/IP config, the port 63649 is set in TCP Dynamic Ports.
 I try to turn off the firewall, and its the same (timeout). Outside Docker, i can connect to SQL, by Dbeaver or MSSMS.

Comment: Any idea of my problem?

Comment: If I understand correctly you're saying the same host that fails in docker, can connect outside of docker.  Only thing I can think of is whether 192.168.1.165 conflicts with a docker network, but that wouldn't conflict with the default network

Comment: I created an Ubuntu VM, and run a Docker, and it works fine. It's probably a Docker desktop bug. Thanks